# How Can I Optimize My Scene Further?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, scene

So, my computer doesn't exactly perform like it has an RTX 4090 GPU in it. Which is why I constantly have to do everything in my power to OPTIMIZE a scene and remove those unnecessary complexities that try to kill my computer. :(

I'm kind of stuck in a hole here. I've already done a lot of optimizing for a scene im working on that has a wheat patch and trees. Overall, it's a farm. The wheat is really low poly so getting close-up shots on it is not even really an option anymore (which is unfortunate). I used an image plane for the leaves and the trees and the trees themselves are already becoming pretty low poly. But as of right now, my viewport is lagging and slowly choking to death. I'll be adding more things like grass and flower on the ground as well as a barn. So, I think you know what will happen if my computer is ALREADY struggling with this.

> **The main question: How can I optimize this scene further?**

The viewport is kind of grainy but this is how it looks in rendered view right now. It lags when you navigate around the scene. (the geometry count is at the top corner):
[image]

It's mostly the hair particle systems for the wheat and geometry node setups for the leaves and trees that are causing this. My pc can handle the geometry count without any significant problems IF there weren't 250k objects. :[

[image]

> **My System Specs:**
>
> **GPU: `Nvidia GTX 1650`**
>
> **CPU: `11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11400F @ 2.60GHz`**
>
> **RAM: `16GB`**

I'm gonna get a 4070 soon but it will be in a while so I need some way to manage for now. All help will be immensely appreciated!

Comment: did u bake everything? the problem is, we don't know much about your scene...so we can just ask. Is your hair animated? if yes, is it baked? Whenever Blender provides a cache setting - i would bake it so that it will speed up.

Comment: Nothing is animated yet or baked yet. I've provided the file in the question.

Comment: one (quick) way to make it quicker is to lower the display amount of your children in your particle system e.g. to 5 (helped on my site a bit)

Comment: another quick way might be to change density in your GN setup like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhb9p.png so just if it is in viewport, the density will be lowered. of course, the lower the number, the quicker will be your viewport. hope that helps a bit.

Comment: This Helps. Thanks!